# create a unique filename from a SQL statement in PHP

Tags: php

I would like to convert long SQL commands into unique filenames for a caching exercise.
I am currently using the `md5()` of each SQL command but am unsure of whether these would be unique.

Would the `md5($sql)` result in unique filenames per SQL statement?

And would those `md5` strings always be the same for the same SQL statement? They would need to be for me.

Thanks very much!

Comment: I need it to be unique per SQL statement, not unique for every instance of an SQL statement. Ie "select * from staff" would need to yield the same filename each time, but that would need to be a different filename from "select * from users", if that makes sense

Comment: I think it's actually quite a clever caching method indeed! Simple, yet no reason to not be effective at all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

md5 will be unique (except in exceptionally rare cases of collision) for a unique input string - so you're doing the right thing.  SHA1 will be even better.

Answer (score 3):

It'll be reasonably unique enough to never be a problem. That's the entire point of MD5, to create unique hashes for unique input. Even though MD5 is not perfect, the chance that you'll accidentally find a collision is so low as to be non-existent for all practical intends and purposes. And since MD5 is really fast, it's a good choice.

Comment: "That's the entire point of MD5, to create unique hashes for unique input." I do not agree at all. This is wrong. The point of hashes, including the md5 hash, it to give non reversible cryptography and  checksum.

Comment: @Skrol How's this different? For both these purposes you need unique hash values for unique input. That's pretty much the definition of a checksum.

Comment: sorry but this is wrong. "to create unique something for unique input" in the definition of a function. Any function is like this. This is basical. And a Hash IS a function by its definition. So the sentence you've written just says that MD5 is a Hash. A hash never gives unique results.

Comment: @Skrol So basically, what I've written is not wrong. I'll happily admit that it's on the general side, but I wrote it in the context of the question. I think we're saying the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that all depends on what the statement is. If you ever have the same two statements then no they would not be unique.

You could append the current date or time to the string though, example:

```
$newsql = $sql.date('Y-m-d H:m:s');
md5($newsql);
```

You could also use the `strtotime()` function as well to generate a number only timestamp.

Alternatively, you could append the `NOW()` MySQL command in your SQL, assuming you're returning data, then it will be unique with a time at the end.

Not sure why you'd be making files from statements though?

---

**EDIT**

My Apologies, the poster DOES want them to be unique, the above will ensure they are NOT unique.

Comment: I thought the whole point was to have two identical statements produce the same hash. The OP's talking about caching after all.

Comment: Silly silly me..... Sorry people, I totally misread the "Needs to be unique" part.

Answer (score 0):

Md5 does a hash which is not unique. Nevertheless it has one chance on 10^36 to have a collision with another hashed string.

If you want to do a cache which is totally sure to not have collision, You can save both the query and the result of the query in the cached file. Then when you retrieve the file cache using the md5 of the SQL statement , you can also check that the SQL statement is the same.

Example of cache file :

sql_cache_fc25e47b204dc615d96749180c72cbf8.php:

```
<?php
$sql = 'SELECT id, name FROM table1 ORDER BY id';
$result = array( 0=> array('id'=>1, 'name'=>'bob'), 1=> array('id'=>2, 'name'=>'tom') );
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add `uniqid()` to each $sql that you're hashing like the following:

```
md5($sql.uniqid())
```

to make it even more unique.

Answer (score -1):

I'm just doing this in my CMS, most systems would allow a filename of 255 characters, and you could create a long md5 hash by using manipulations of the string.

For example

```
$sql='Your MySQL String';
$filename='mysqlcache_'.md5($sql).md5(strrev($sql)).md5('MYSQL'.$sql).sha1($sql);
```

So the string will be 11+32+32+32+40=147 characters long and there is much less chance of the cache files colliding.

Comment: that's killing overkill!